# magento 2 minicart remove item message with product name

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to add the product name along with this message:

> Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Need to override `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\minicart.js`